# XCode Interface Builder : How to configure interface builder to show an 3.5 inch iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I want interface builder to display a 3.5 inch iphone mockup and work on it. Where do I configure it?

Comment: This is one of the (rare) questions tagged "xcode" that **are actually** about Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the main .xib file's property by selecting it and go to `Assistant Editor` and within `Simulated Metrics` section, size property to `Retina 3.5 Full Screen`

here i have mentioned how to change the size using `storyboard` 
[image]

Comment: I don't know if it matters by I have `storyboard` file. Do you mean to open the file as source? When I open the assistance editor It shows mr the view controller?

Comment: If you have storyboard, you should select the `View Controller` in your storyboard and set the size as i mentioned, it works in both ways, and please accept the answer if it helps your cause thanks. if you are using .xib then you should select your .xib file in set the size as i mentioned

Comment: you can see my updated answer, I have shown with the screen shot also. i hope you have solved this issue already.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Size` property of main UIView in .xib to `Retina 3,5 Full Screen`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard file: Select the view controller and you will find the simulated metrics in the Attributes Inspector. Then simply change the size from 'Inferred' to 'Retina 3.5 Full Screen'.

The easiest way to select a view controller in a storyboard is to click the left bar item below your view - see screenshot.

[image]